# Sending JSON via REST using DynamoDB attribute name

Tags: json, rest, api, amazon-dynamodb, postman

I have a field in my Car POJO class that looks like this:

```
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "release_year")
private int year;
```

I want to add a Car to my database by sending a POST request via Postman. I was hoping that my JSON body could look like this:

```
{
  "release_year": 2015
}
```

It is not possible, I have to use 'year' instead. In my dynamoDB, the field is called 'release_year';

My question is: is it possible to use 'release_year' in my POST request somehow, but still keep 'year' in the POJO class? Or do I have to rename the field to 'release_year'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the annotation @JsonSetter(valueName) over the fields would suffice for my case. I can use

```
{ 
    release_year: 2015 
}
```

for my POST request, and when I use GET request, that value will be release_year instead of year like before.

I guess @DynamoDBAttribute only works for the columns in the database and does not affect the requests.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have exp with Java but seem `@DynamoDBAttribute` annotation only works on function level. So pls try

```
  private int year;

  @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "release_year")
  public int getYear() { return year; }
  public void setYear(int year) { this.year = year; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I forgot to mention I am using lombok, that's why I don't explicitly write getters and setters and setters. However, I tried without lombok, but it still did not work.

Comment: No, the object is saved successfully, but the year has value '0'.